# JQuery ui autocomplete trigger again on same input field

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

i am using jquery ui autocomlete for one of my projects, it is working fine bt what i really want is as soon as i hit enter on one of the key suggestions another suggestion box should get displayed displaying some values, so after selecting that second value the whole key-value pair gets enters in the input text field

```
    var source1 = ['key1','key2',key3',....etc] ; 
var source2 = [ 'value1','value2','value3',....etc] ;             $('#firstInput').autocomplete
({ source: source1, 
select: function(event, ui) 
{ $('#firstInput').autocomplete({ source:source2}); 
} 
});
```

i applied the above code but dsn't work.........only autocomplete gets applied for the first time..:( –

Comment: Could you provide some of your code to complete your description?

Comment: Have you tried configuring `select` function? that may help

Comment: var source1 = ['key1','key2',key3',....etc] ;                                       var source2 = [ 'value1','value2','value3',....etc] ;                        $('#firstInput').autocomplete({
source: source1, 
select: function(event, ui) { 
   $('#firstInput').autocomplete({ source:source2});
}
});                                                                                                                                 i applied the above code but dsn't work.........only autocomplete gets applied for the first time..:(

Answer (score 1):

Try configure `select` function with auto-complete, for example below -

```
$('#firstInput').autocomplete({
source: [ 'value1', 'value2' ], 
select: function(event, ui) { 
   // this handler can be used to trigger other event.  
   console.log(ui.item.id);
}
```

});

Comment: I have tried the above solution but it doesn't work , if you have achieved what i am asking can u please show me the specific code you have written inside select event, thanks for answering